# Not able to hide radio buttons based on the year selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display some radio buttons/button based on some condition using jquery. However it's not working. Can any one let me know what's wrong in the code? The scenario is

1. If the user selects 2014 or 2013, it should display first radio button
2. If the user selects other than these years, based on the difference between the current year & year selected, I need to display the number of radio buttons.

My code is

```
$('#eForm_registeredDate').change(function() {
    $('#divncb').removeClass('dontshow');
    var that = $(this);
    var currentYear = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear());
    var registeredYear = parseInt(that.val());    
    if(registeredYear == currentYear || currentYear == (registeredYear + 1)) {        
        $( 'input:radio[name="ncbyear"]').not(':eq(0)').hide();
    } else {
        var noNcbYear =  currentYear - registeredYear;
        $( 'input:radio[name="ncbyear"]').not(':gt('+noNcbYear+')').hide();
    }
});
```

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5ept4r74/3/

Comment: The best option is not hiding the radio button, I think. You can change the "checked" attribute instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Twain is right, you should wrap your raido buttons for hiding their texts aswell.

Also you need to show all the radios when any change happened for resetting the view of the objects on each user interaction.

[**Here is working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ept4r74/32/).

jQuery:

```
$('#eForm_registeredDate').change(function() {
    $('#divncb').removeClass('dontshow');
    var that = $(this);
    var currentYear = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear());
    var registeredYear = parseInt(that.val());  

    $('#divncb label').show();//reset view here
    if(registeredYear == currentYear || currentYear == (registeredYear + 1)) {        
        $( 'input:radio[name="ncbyear"]').not(':eq(0)').parent().hide();  
    } else {
        var noNcbYear =  currentYear - registeredYear;
        $( 'input:radio[name="ncbyear"]').not(':gt('+noNcbYear+')').parent().hide();
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div id="divncb" class="dontshow">
    <label>
         <input type="radio" name="ncbyear" value="0" checked>1 year(0%)
    </label>
    <label>
         <input type="radio" name="ncbyear" value="20">2 years(20%)
    </label>
    <label>
         <input type="radio" name="ncbyear" value="25" checked>3 year(25%)
    </label>
    <label>
         <input type="radio" name="ncbyear" value="35">4 years(35%)
    </label>
    <label>
         <input type="radio" name="ncbyear" value="45" checked>5 year(45%)
    </label>
    <label>
         <input type="radio" name="ncbyear" value="50">&gt; 5 years(50%)
    </label>
 </div>
```

Comment: No Barlas, you didn't understand my question. When the user selects 2014 or 2013, It should show only only 1 year(0%). Others should be hidden. If the user selects 2011, it should display up to 3 Years(25%)

Comment: your radios are correctly hidden, but the text behind them are not. You could wrap them in a span element with a class to hide them ;)

Comment: the radios should probably be wrapped in `<label>`, not `<span>`

Comment: also not sure about checking multiple radios with the same name - even though they're not visible at the same time this seems wrong to me, this should maybe also be handled in the event.

Comment: Awesome. I was just trying the same to add div & span. You're the first. Thanks mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped your **radio field and label** in a **span** and doing **show and hide** on the wrapper span
**HTML**

```
  <div id="divncb" class="dontshow">
        <span><input type="radio" name="ncbyear" value="0" checked>1 year(0%)</span>
        <span><input type="radio" name="ncbyear" value="20">2 years(20%)</span>
        <span><input type="radio" name="ncbyear" value="25" checked>3 year(25%)</span>
        <span><input type="radio" name="ncbyear" value="35">4 years(35%)</span>
        <span><input type="radio" name="ncbyear" value="45" checked>5 year(45%)</span>
        <span><input type="radio" name="ncbyear" value="50">&gt; 5 years(50%)</span>
     </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#eForm_registeredDate').change(function() {
    $('#divncb').removeClass('dontshow');
    var that = $(this);
    var currentYear = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear());
    var registeredYear = parseInt(that.val());    
    $( 'input:radio[name="ncbyear"]').parent().show();
    if(registeredYear == currentYear || currentYear == (registeredYear + 1)) {        
          $( 'input:radio[name="ncbyear"]').not(':eq(0)').parent().hide();
    } else {
        var noNcbYear =  currentYear - registeredYear;
                $( 'input:radio[name="ncbyear"]').not(':gt('+noNcbYear+')').parent().hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit. It's solved. I appreciate your support.

Comment: Yeah. Hopefully I can get help from you when I stuck up with something else. Can I have your email ID if you don't mind?

Comment: yeah any time..that you can get by clicking on my name

Comment: I can't see anything on clicking your name. Just email me .. alinizam.shaik@gmail.com.. I can add you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that's what you're trying to do

```
var radios = $('input:radio[name="ncbyear"]');
var registeredDate = $('#eForm_registeredDate');
registeredDate.change(function() {
    $('#divncb').removeClass('dontshow');
    var that = $(this);
    var currentYear = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear(),10);
    var registeredYear = parseInt(that.val(),10);
    var diff = (currentYear-registeredYear)>0?(currentYear-registeredYear):1;

    radios.each(function(index,radio){
        if(diff>=index+1)
            $(radio).show();
        else
            $(radio).hide();
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why did you add "10" here ?var currentYear = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear(),10);

Comment: But, anyways thats not working. Please check this fiddle. The correct working one http://jsfiddle.net/5ept4r74/34/

Comment: the `parseInt` function takes a sencod aguments: radix, if your string begins with a "0", it is interpreted as octal number. And it is working you wanna hide radio, it hides radio...

Comment: And you should always store your jQuery elements in variables. If you don't, jQuery has to parse to parse the entire dom to find them each time you call `$(selector)`.

Comment: If possible can you please prepare a fiddle with it? Along with hiding the texts?